# How do I create a nested select menu based off a nested ul list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a "nested" select menu based off an nested HTML ul list. For example, a user is presented with a select menu of categories, and then picking an option of that root category will open another select menu with sub-categories. (The cycle continues if the sub-category has sub-categories. I want to be able to open an any number of sub-category sub-menus based off the ul list.)

For example, given this code on the page:

```
<ul id="select-menu-layout" style="display: none">
  <li>A option
    <ul>
      <li>a1 name</li>
      <li>a2 name</li>
      <li>a3 name</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>B option
    <ul>
      <li>b1 name</li>
      <li>b2 name
        <ul>
          <li>b21 choice</li>
          <li>b22 choice</li>
          <li>b23 choice</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>b3 name</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>C name</li>
</ul>

<!-- select menus will be shown in the container below -->
<div class="select-menu-container"></div>
```

In the example above, there will one select menu shown initially:

```
<select>
  <option>A option</option>
  <option>B option</option>
  <option>C option</option>
</select>
```

Selecting the "B option" will then show this second select menu (based on the HTML list above):

```
<select>
  <option>b1 name</option>
  <option>b2 name</option>
  <option>b3 name</option>
</select>
```

Selecting the "b2 name" will then show this third select menu:

```
<select>
  <option>b21 choice</option>
  <option>b22 choice</option>
  <option>b23 choice</option>
</select>
```

I'm assuming you'll need javascript/jQuery to do this? I'm thinking along the lines of this code (although I'm probably very wrong):

```
<div class="select-menu-container"></div>

<script>
function addSelectMenu(node){
  $(".select-menu-container").append("<select style='display: none'></select>")
  node.each(function(){
    var name = $(this).val()
     $("select:last").append("<option>" + name + "</option>")
  })
}

$("ul").each(function(){
  addSelectMenu($(this))
})
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to convert an ul/li list in a series of select elements with a behaviour like a nested collapsible list a possible solution can be based on recursive approach.

Each select must be linked to the previous one in order to toggle visibility.

The snippet:

```js
function createSelectFromUl(ele, parentLink) {
    var txtParentNode = parentLink || '';
    var options = ele.map(function (idx, ele) {
        var txt = $(ele).contents().filter(function (idx, ele) {
            if (ele.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                return true;
            }
        }).text().trim();
        return $('<option/>', {text: txt})
    });
    if (ele.children('ul').length == 0) {
        return [$('<select/>', {parentNode: txtParentNode}).append(options.toArray())];
    }
    var retVal = [$('<select/>', {parentNode: txtParentNode}).append(options.toArray())];
    ele.children('ul').each(function (idx, ele) {
        txtParentNode = $(ele.parentNode).contents().filter(function (idx, ele) {
            if (ele.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                return true;
            }
        }).text().trim();
        var childSelects = createSelectFromUl($(ele).children('li'), txtParentNode);

        $.merge(retVal, childSelects);
    });
    return retVal;
}
$(function () {
    var seleEles = createSelectFromUl($('#select-menu-layout > li'));
    $('.select-menu-container').append(seleEles);
    $('.select-menu-container select:gt(0)').hide();

    $('.select-menu-container select').on('change', function (e) {
        var txtParentNode = $(this).val();
        $(this).nextAll().hide();
        $('.select-menu-container select[parentNode="' + txtParentNode + '"]').toggle();
    }).trigger('change');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul id="select-menu-layout" style="display: none">
    <li>A option
        <ul>
            <li>a1 name</li>
            <li>a2 name</li>
            <li>a3 name</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>B option
        <ul>
            <li>b1 name</li>
            <li>b2 name
                <ul>
                    <li>b21 choice</li>
                    <li>b22 choice</li>
                    <li>b23 choice</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>b3 name</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>C name</li>
</ul>

<div class="select-menu-container"></div>
```

Comment: You're absolutely incredible! The solution works perfectly. The code looks great and you made it simple for a novice like me to understand. Thank you so much!! :)